# Using a static library in c (.a file)

Tags: c, shell, gcc

I am trying to create a static library using a shell script.

For creating the library I used following script:

```c
gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror *.c
ar -cr libft.a *.o
```

There are 5 different functions in 5 .c files.

Now I wanted to test the library and created a main.c file with this content:

```c
#include "libft.a"

int     main(void)
{
    ft_putstr("hello");
}
```

Compiling the main.c (with gcc main.c) returns 419 warning and at least 20 errors looking something like this:

```
./libft.a:4:492: warning: null character ignored [-Wnull-character]
  ...<U+0000>UH<89><E5>H<83><EC><U+0010>@<88>}<FF><BF><U+0001><U+0000><U+0000><U+0000>H<8D>u...
```

Before this I was working with .h files which worked fine but this time I wasn't supposed to create a .h file so I don't what to do know.

Comment: Only include `.h` files. Always write header files for functions to be called from other `.c` files. The `.a` is to be provided to the linker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#include "file_name"` means like "please copy and paste the contents of the file `file_name` here", so it shouldn't be used with `.a` file.

You can write the declaration of the function to use directly instead of using `.h` file.

```
/* guessed from usage, please use correct argument and return type */
void ft_putstr(const char*);

int     main(void)
{
    ft_putstr("hello");
}
```

Then compile the source code with linking with the library:

```
gcc main.c -lft
```

Comment: Thats not my question. I want to now how to test my libft.a file. Its a task I need to do that's why I shouldn't use a different way.

Comment: Note that you'll probably need `gcc main.c -lft -L.`

Comment: what does -lft mean? I used gcc main.c libft.a. And now it works.

Comment: and is there a way to use libft.a without using an extra flag for gcc ?

Answer (score 0):

When you compile your `main.c`, add the library name to it like this:

```
gcc main.c libft.a
```